# Are there informed speculations about what is the next Mac that is going to be upgraded?

Tags: mac, hardware, apple-inc

There are five lines of Macs (MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac mini, iMac, Mac Pro), and AFAIK Apple has almost always updated only one at a time, leaving the others a bit behind.

Now, it should be easy to keep track of the most recently updated, hence the odds of an update for the older models increases, and this is what I would call an "informed speculation" at a very basic level.

Is there any site which aims to keep tracks of these updates, and possibly adds commentary on product line changes?

Comment: I would disagree with the characterization that an update to a Mac Pro somehow leaves an Air behind. They serve different needs. Just because a new pickup truck is released, that doesn't obsolete a line of motorcycles and cars. What's the problem you are trying to solve by knowing the release cycle of all OS X hardware? Is there something tying these together which you can elaborate?

Comment: @bmike if you buy a Mac the day before that model gets upgraded, you will basically have an inferior product spending the same amount of cash. Hence, you can say that the real value of a Mac decreases with time from release to the upgrade. As soon as it's released it's at full value, so if you instead buy something else, you get a product which _isn't_ at full value instead. This is what I meant, hope it's clear now.

Comment: Your comment seems to steer this further off course for the site. If you look at the [help] - you'll see we ask "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." and avoid hardware shopping questions. This seems over-broad, overly speculative without some edits to narrow the scope of the problem to be solved here.

Comment: @bmike but... this is answerable, and **has** been answered...

Comment: Please open a thread on [meta] if the close reason doesn't make sense...

Comment: @bmike no time for arguing on SO any more, sorry, you are free to run your site as you see fit even if it doesn't make sense: I got my answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**MacRumors Buyer's Guide**](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/) seems to provide the best predictions for updates. They use the average timescale for updates to provide a guess as to whether an update will come soon. They also include prominent rumours towards updates.

[image]